# NLTK Python Extract .txt files from a local folder, file recall issue

Tags: nltk

I'm writing a simple program on Python/NLTK (Windows PC) for a university exam, I'm frankly new in the world of coding.

I have a folder on my computer called "Reviews" where there are 50 .txt files.
My objective is to extract these files from the folder and recall it; thereafter to create some lists with the files and compare it with some techniques like (as example) FreqDist.

### Firstly I did the "import" of nltk, os, PlaintextCorpusReader.

```
import nltk
from nltk import os
from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
```

### All works. Then I tried to see the content of the folder.

```
foldercontent = PlaintextCorpusReader("C:\\Users\\Mgmura\\Desktop\\Reviews", '.*', encoding='latin1')
print(foldercontent.fileids())
```

### Also here, all works. The output shows all the 50 .txt files in the folder. So I tried to do something (show sents) with the content of a single .txt file.

```
foldercontent.sents('it_quattroruote_giulia.txt')
```

### The output shows some sents so it works fine.

### Now there's the real issue. If I tried to recall a single file there's a "name error" like below.

> ```
> > NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> > last) <ipython-input-1-3dd9ed6446c9> in <module>()
> > ----> 1 it_quattroruote_giulia
> > 
> > NameError: name 'it_quattroruote_giulia' is not defined
> ```

So the real question is: how I can assign a name to every .txt files and recall it?

Thanks in advance

Marco